# How does "make" work in "What kind of person makes a good friend?"

Tags: phrases, verbs

> What kind of person makes a good friend?

I have seen this kind of sentence several times; never understood why it is normal in English. It means that there are people with specific traits of character who can be good friends, OK. But why "make"? It seems to be a sentence, where person can create a friend for somebody and not out of himself, but out of somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Make* has a lengthy list of possible interpretations, see [the American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=make) entry.

The sense of make in this context seems to fall somewhere around:

> 16. To be suited for: *Oak makes strong furniture.*
> 17. To develop into: *will make a fine doctor.*

As far as the similarity to other senses of *make*, the construction is similar to one in which there is a straightforward object or a predicative complement:

> She made him a good husband  [object-oriented predicative complement]
>
> 5.a. To cause to be or become
>
> She made (him) a teddy bear [object]
>
> 2.To bring into existence by shaping, modifying, or putting together material; construct

The context usually makes clear which sense of *make* is intended.

There are, of course, other options than *make* in most situations, but they tend to sound more formal:

> What kind of person is suited to be a good friend?
>
> What kind of person develops into a good friend?

Answer (score 2):

It is OED sense 21a of the verb ***to make*** - meaning ***to amount t0, to fully constitute, to be the essential criterion of etc***.

> 21(a). transitive.  [Compare the classical Latin and post-classical
>   Latin use of *facere* in e.g. *regem non faciunt opes (Seneca), non
>   tonsura facit monachum* (Neckam, a1217), and the Middle French and
>   French use in e.g. *l'habit ne faict poinct le moine* (Rabelais, 1532).]
>   Of an adjunct or feature: to be sufficient to constitute; to be the
>   essential criterion of. Chiefly in proverbial or quasi-proverbial
>   uses, mainly in negative contexts.
>
> 1340   Ayenbite (1866) 165 (MED)   Þe cloþinge ne makeþ naȝt þane
>   monek, ne þe armes þane knyȝt.
>
> ?a1425   Constit. Masonry (Royal 17 A.i) l. 726 in J. O. Halliwell
>   Early Hist. Freemasonry in Eng. (1844) 38   Gode maneres maken a mon.
>
> c1475   tr. A. Chartier Quadrilogue (Univ. Coll. Oxf.) (1974) 231
>   But now [to] [MS two] can guerde a swerde and doo vpon an habirgeon
>   suffiseth to make a nwe capteyn.
>
> a1500  (▸c1425)    Andrew of Wyntoun Oryg. Cron. Scotl. (Nero) v. l.
>   3877   Ȝoure purpure may noucht prestis ma.
>
> 1546   J. Heywood Dialogue Prouerbes Eng. Tongue ii. v. sig. Hiii
>   One swalow maketh not sommer.
>
> 1649   R. Lovelace Poems (1864) 119   Stone walls doe not a prison
>   make, Nor iron bars a cage.
>
> 1734   A. Pope Ess. Man: Epist. IV 193   Worth makes the Man, and want
>   of it the Fellow.
>
> 1859   Ld. Tennyson Guinevere in Idylls of King 250   And courtliness,
>   and the desire of fame, And love of truth, and all that makes a man.
>
> 1861   Temple Bar 3 256   A long beard does not make a philosopher.
>
> 1893   National Observer 7 Oct. 531/2   One actress does not make a
>   play.
>
> 1933   J. Hilton Lost Horizon 3   Still, it did happen—and it goes
>   some way to show that  clothes make the man, doesn't it? 1990
>   Atlantic Nov. 8/1   The quick and dirty reference to one example that
>   supports his argument and two that don't hardly makes a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Plumbing the depths of the entry for **make** in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make) one finds:

> 10c: to form the essential being of
>
> *clothes make the man*

(obviously here used metaphorically and hyperbolically in the well-known idiom)

So 'What makes a good friend?' may be paraphrased 'What are the essential attributes of a good friend?'

Answer (score -1):

Make is a word with several uses, and I think there are two different uses connected to the example in the title. Firstly, to make friends is to form a friendship with somebody, to make them into a friend. Secondly, a statement such as "maple wood makes the best tables" is correct English, and in this example means that a skilled craftsman can make the best tables from maple wood. So your example is about making a person into a friend, and asking about the traits that would make the person a good friend.

Answer (score -1):

The expression [**make friends**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20friends) is an established idiom:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to become someone's friend
>   // Sometimes it is hard for children to *make* new *friends*.
>   —often + *with*
>   // She's very good at *making friends with* people from all walks of life.

Since it's an idiom, it might not be possible to analyze the *make* portion of the expression in a meaningful way.

From the main sense of [*idiom*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   an expression in the usage of a language that is peculiar to itself either in having a meaning that cannot be derived from the conjoined meanings of its elements (such as *up in the air* for "undecided") or in its grammatically atypical use of words (such as *give way*)

---

While this is speculative (again, because idioms commonly defy proper analysis), it could be considered analogously to the end result of a process:

1. "I am going to work on following a *recipe*. At the end of this process, I hope to end up with a *cake*."
   → "I am going to **bake a cake**."
2. "I am going to work on establishing a *friendship*. At the end of this process, I hope to end up with a *friend*."
   → "I am going to **make a friend**."

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider the phrasal verb **make for**. From M-W:

> **[make for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20for)**: to cause (something) to happen or to be more likely, e.g., 'Courtesy makes for safer driving.'

Your example:

> What kind of person **makes for** a good friend?

That is, what "kind of person" can cause "friendship" to happen or be more likely? I tend to think **makes for** makes more sense in your example sentence than *makes*. The latter could be interpreted as follows: "What kind of person makes a good friend, *not for others but for themselves*?" **Makes for** eliminates the ambiguity that you yourself noted in your question.

Comment: Okay, what's with the nonsensical downvote with no explanation?